Python in Rstudio with reticulate: gsub error
I want to use python in Rstudio by reticulate. But the non-utf8 characters I use in comments cause an error.
For example, when I run,
reticulate::repl_python()

and then, I run in Python
# öngörü

I get the following error:
Error in gsub(“^\\\\s*|\\\\s*$”, “”, contents) : input string 1 is invalid
Warning:
In gsub(“^\\\\s*|\\\\s*$”, “”, contents) :
  unable to translate '# <f6>ng<f6>r<fc>' to a wide string

Note that I didn't run gsub() manually. I think R used it in the backend to throw the error message.
To solve the problem, I ran the code below, but it didn't work.
file.edit(file.path(“~”, “.Rprofile”))
Sys.setlocale(“LC_CTYPE”, locale=“English.65001”)

Is there a solution to this problem?

Try specifying "useBytes = TRUE" in gsub. However must check the result as some unexpected translation migth occur (although i think when the regexp match ASCII it is usually not a problem)

Please post full code block not line snippets. It is unclear how R or Python begins or ends.

I edited the question to make the start and end of R and Python explicit.
Note that I didn't use the gsub command, I think R used it in the backend to throw the error message.
